# Convert into a decimal number

Tags: arithmetic, decimal-expansion

How can we convert in $\mathbb{Q}$ the inverse of $1{,}2^2$ (i.e the number $\frac{1}{
1{,}2^2}$) into a decimal number?

Also how could we show that with the complex multiplication $\cdot$ then $(G, \cdot)$ is a commutative group?

Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Are you using decimal commas, i.e. $1,2^2=1,44$?  so $1,2=\frac{6}{5}$ and  so $1,2^2=\frac{36}{25}$ and $\frac{1}{1,2^2}=\frac{25}{36}$?

Comment: This is not clear.  What does $1,2^2$ mean?  What is $G$?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by $1,2^2$ ? That seems to be an unusual notation.

Comment: Can you clarify your questions?  As you can see from the comments, nobody can sort out what you are asking.

Comment: @lulu I think the person who asked the question lives in somewhere like parts of Europe where they use commas instead of the decimal dots.

Comment: @Puffy  sure, but even with that notation I've never seen an exponent appear to the right of the decimal.  If what is intended is the rational number $1+\frac {2^2}{10}$ that should be clarified.

Comment: Voting to close the question as it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Tip: When using a comma as the decimal separator you get better TeX-spacing when you include the comma in curly braces. So `$1{,}2$`. Surely $1{,}2$ looks better than $1,2$ when the intention is to write *one plus two tenths*. TeX-spacing rules are designed for an environment where a comma is either a list separator or a punctuation mark between parts of a sentence. Those cases call for different spacing.

Comment: @lulu: Huh? Would you insist on writing the number as $(1.2)^2$? Or wonder whether $1.2+3$ means $1+\frac{2+3}{10}$? The decimal point binds _stronger_ than every other operation, including exponentiation.

Comment: Anyway $$1{,}2^{-2}=\frac{100}{144}=\frac{25}{36}=\frac{25}4\cdot\frac19=\frac{625}{100}\cdot\frac19$$ where I collected the powers of two and five (divisors of ten) of the denominator to the first factor). Here $625/9=69+\dfrac49$, so you get the answer by first writing the easy expansion of $69\dfrac49$ and then moving the decimal separator by two positions.

Comment: @HenningMakholm  sure, but there is no difficulty at all writing the reciprocal of $1.44$ as a decimal so I find it hard to believe that this is the question.  I assumed the OP intended something else.  If I'm wrong (which, I grant, I probably am) the point is easily clarified.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, your question isn't very clear so I'll guess you're asking us to convert $1 \over 1.2^2$ into a decimal number.

$1 \over 1.2^2$

$=$ $1 \over 1.44$

$=$$100 \over 100$$\div$$144 \over 100$

$=$$100 \over 100$$\times$$100 \over 144$

$=$$100 \over 1$$\times$$1 \over 144$

$=$$100 \over 144$

$=$$0.69\overline4$